# How to remove list element and return new list?

Tags: python, list

How to remove an item by index from python list and assign that list to a new one?
For example, I have list `list1 = [1,2,3,4]` , I can use python `del list1[0]`   to remove first item in it. But how can I make an assignment like this `list2 = del list1[0]` to return *list2* from *list1* deleted the first object?

```
>list1.pop(i)
>print(list1)
```

returns a list object, but I want to assign this to a new variable. If I use this syntax. It returns an integer.

```
>var1 = list1.pop(i)
>print(type(var1))
...<class 'int'>
```

Comment: Should the original list referenced by `list1` remain unchanged?

Comment: `pop` does not return a `list`, but whatever type the element ist, that you popped. You could go with `list2 = [list1.pop(i)]`

Comment: @brainfuck4d  ` list2 = [list1.pop(i)]`  returns a list with one *int* in it, the one that was popped out. I want to return remaining items as a new list.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, ` list1 ` should remain unchanged.

Comment: By the way, there is no built-in function. `list2 = list1[:i]+list1[i+1: ]` will help :)

Comment: I thought the item should be deleted from `list1` how can it remain unchanged then?

Comment: I introduced that part wrongly sorry. It indeed should delete an item from `list1` so it will be changed. But it should return another list, which is equal to list1 minus that item which is deleted.